# How to webscrape when downloads are involved?

Tags: web-scraping, rselenium

I was wondering how to web scrape text from multiple [bills](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-bill/6637/text/) when the text needs to be downloaded to view? Is there a RSelenium answer for this?

Comment: Which is the file you intent to download?

Comment: Could you provide an example, please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The link is the example. I can't scrape the XML or pdf versions of the bill and the txt option doesn't work.

Comment: download.file("https://www.congress.gov/116/bills/hr6637/BILLS-116hr6637ih.pdf", dest = "fail.pdf") works just fine.
You have to be clearer about what you really want, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: to download pdf file use `download.file("https://www.congress.gov/116/bills/hr6637/BILLS-116hr6637ih.pdf", dest = "fail.pdf", mode = 'wb')`